# Jquery Ajax call in asp.net Progress Bar update

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I am doing jquery ajax call in asp.net, I am getting some value from database in a textbox and on base of it I am making jquery progressbar.
Its getting value in textbox, but its not taking value of progress bar first time, I have to reload the page for value of progress bar.
Below is my code

```
 $(function () {
        GetValue();
        var l_count= parseInt($("#txtcount").val());

        $("#sliderlicense").progressbar({
            max: 100,
            value: l_count
        });           
    });

    function GetValue() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "MyPage.aspx/GetCount", //url to point your webmethod     
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (Result) {
                $("#txtcount").val(Result.d);
            },
            error: function () { alert('error'); }
        });
    }


 [System.Web.Services.WebMethod()]
        public static string GetCount()
        {
          //Get values from DB and return it
        }
```

I also tried with document.ready but no luck, Which event of Jquery should I use to make my progress bar on first time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

**async:false,** add to ajax call

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        GetValue();
        var l_count= parseInt($("#txtcount").val());

        $("#sliderlicense").progressbar({
            max: 100,
            value: l_count
        });

    });
})
function GetValue() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "MyPage.aspx/GetCount", //url to point your webmethod     
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        async:false,
        success: function (Result) {
            $("#txtcount").val(Result.d);
        },
        error: function () { alert('error'); }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

ajax means [Asynchronous](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_I/O), that said, means that you need wait untill your first request suceed, and after pocess with value.

Some pseudocode:

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "MyPage.aspx/GetCount", //url to point your webmethod     
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (Result) {
            $("#txtcount").val(Result.d);

            //HERE ASSIGN TO PROGRESS BAR 
            var l_count= parseInt($("#txtcount").val());

            $("#sliderlicense").progressbar({
             max: 100,
             value: l_count
            });
            // --------------------------
        },
        error: function () { alert('error'); }
    });
```